# Drupal 7: Default Theme Being Removed After Clearing Cache

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am encountering a strange issue where the site theme is being removed after running either "Clear all caches" within Drupals Performance section or via the following drush command: `cc all`

In addition to this, the theme is also removed if I simply navigate to the "Appearance" section within the Drupal admin. So I never get to see it set as a default template.

The theme is running fine if I do not do either of the above. This is encountered in both development and production environments.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check drupal and php logs ?

Comment: Try to use registry rebuild https://drushcommands.com/drush-7x/registry-rebuild/registry-rebuild/

Comment: I think I resolved the issue. When the site in question got handed over to me, the custom theme was housed under /sites/<sitename>/themes/. When I moved the theme to /theme, it worked. Not sure how this has ever worked previously... Could there be a reference I missed?